# PyCharm print error and changing interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, interpreter

I am using PyCharm which is using Python 2.7 interpreter. I write the following code and for an input name `'d'` the output should be

```
d 1
d 2 # ... etc.
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
('d', 1)
('d', 2)
('d', 3)
('d', 4) # etc ...
```

This is the code:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")

for i in range(1, 10):
    print(name, i)
```

Also can someone tell me how to change my interpreter to Python 3.7. I've searched the help section for Pycharm but couldnt find "Project settings" section.

Comment: That `print` behaviour is **correct** for Python 2.x. See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html (and note that even 3.5 isn't [released](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/) until September!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with 2.7 vs. 3.x syntax for the print. If you change the interpreter to 3x, it should print as you expect.

Go to Preferences, then Project and then Project Interpreter. You should be able to change the version there.